# I want To show Tax on Checkout page but not apply on shipping Amount

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want To show Tax on the Checkout page but not apply to the shipping Amount. please find the below calculation.
This is a Formula:

```
Subtotal: 100
Tax=100*20/100=20
Shipping =50
Order Total =:100+20+50
```

it's possible in Magento 2 or need to do some code for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento makes it simple for you.

Navigate to `STORES > Settings > Configuration` then expand the `SALES` panel and select `Tax`
Expand the `Tax Classes` panel and select `Tax Class For Shipping` as `None`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I showed order data on success page.

> $order->getTaxAmount();
>
> $order->getShippingAmount();

Check for reference.